# Setting automatic charge levels in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, battery, dell-inspiron

I'm using Linux and I'd like to make my computer start charging when I am at 30% level and stop charging when I'm at 80%, because it's mostly plugged in and I want to increase my battery life. Is this possible to do with some setting, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

1. This requires *hardware* in the PC to actually terminate charging. On a PC I use, which has built-in battery charge limiting, Ubuntu 18.04 handles charge state well, keeping the PC at 80% (well, actually 79%) when plugged into mains. [ASUS, Lenovo](https://windowsreport.com/software-stop-battery-charging/) and Toshiba are among the manufacturers that have implemented charge limiting on some models.

[image: Ubuntu maintains constant charge level]

2. Your proposed charging scheme is a **bad** idea, because [repeated cycling](https://www.mpoweruk.com/life.htm) damages cells of any chemistryNiMH or Li-ion, for varying reasons. The flux of ions causes the plates to change dimensionally, metallic dendrites can grow to short-circuit the cell, etc. Least damaging storage is probably to keep Li-ion cells at a steady charge state, perhaps ~60% or 80%. See [this article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1149/1945-7111/abae37), for example, on *Degradation of Commercial Lithium-Ion Cells as a Function of Chemistry and Cycling Conditions*.

Comment: what do you mean by keeping them at a steady charge state ~60%? And does ubuntu 18.04 do this automatically or something?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 uses the PC's charge interface, and on those PC's that offer it, it works. And what is there to explain about keeping the charge level steady when plugged in? If the cell capacity is 10 A-h, then keeping it at 6 or at 8 A-h.